# How to write not null and > 25 in SQL raw expression

Tags: sql, controller, laravel-5, query-builder

This is what I have so far to show those that are not Null

```
$memcount = MemberProfile::where(DB::raw('floor(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),birthday) /365) != null'))
```

How do I add "not Null and greater than 25 but less than 35"

Comment: `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` is the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `WHERE [item] IS NOT NULL AND [item] BETWEEN 25 AND 35`. Please check out the between operator.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can take a shortcut here.

No need for the `NOT NULL` predicate additionally if values are already compared with predicate `BETWEEN .. AND ..` (or greater/less than `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`).

```sql
WHERE [item] BETWEEN 25 AND 35
```

will include only non-null items (i.e. filter out NULL values) in the result set.

Try on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/93fc53/2).